# Add 1 to each cell in every row of two columns until a blank cell is reached - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, do-loops

All I'm looking to do is add 1 to a range of cells until it reaches a blank cell. I'm also minus 1 from a another range of cells until it reaches a blank cell. I've currently codded each cell individually but the number of cells with data in changes so isn't really practical.

Here is an extract of code I have written can anyone help me?

```
function Calculations() {
  //Week Number & Week Pay
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  s=SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Money")

  var currVal=s.getRange("C2").getValue()
  var plusVal= currVal +1
  s.getRange("C2") .setValue(plusVal)
  var currVal=s.getRange("B2").getValue()
  var minusVal= currVal -1
  s.getRange("B2") .setValue(minusVal)

  var currVal=s.getRange("C3").getValue()
  var plusVal= currVal +1
  s.getRange("C3") .setValue(plusVal)
  var currVal=s.getRange("B3").getValue()
  var minusVal= currVal -1
  s.getRange("B3") .setValue(minusVal)

  var currVal=s.getRange("C4").getValue()
  var plusVal= currVal +1
  s.getRange("C4") .setValue(plusVal)
  var currVal=s.getRange("B4").getValue()
  var minusVal= currVal -1
  s.getRange("B4") .setValue(minusVal)
}
```

Comment: Please checkout [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)

Comment: I have almost the same prob with this as well please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856661/i-would-like-to-have-a-script-button-which-deducts-values-from-column-a-to-the-t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using A1 or R1C1 notation, I find it easier to just use numbers when getting the cell location (range).

Increment the row number at the end of the loop.  The loop will iterate a maximum of the number of rows with data, and it will break if it finds an empty cell.

```
function Calculations() {
try{
  //Week Number & Week Pay
  var currVal,i,L,lastRow,minusVal,plusVal,ss,sh,theColumn,theRng,theRow;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Get the active spreadsheet
  sh = ss.getSheetByName("Money");//Get a sheet tab by name
  lastRow = sh.getLastRow();//Get the number of the last row with data

  L = lastRow;
  theRow = 2;//Start in row 2

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {//Loop as many times as there is number of rows with data
    theColumn = 3;//Column C

    theRng = sh.getRange(theRow,theColumn);//Get the range which is one cell

    currVal = theRng.getValue();//Get the value in one cell
    //Logger.log('currVal: ' + currVal);

    if (!currVal) {//If there is a blank cell then
      break;//quit the loop
    }

    plusVal= currVal +1;
    theRng.setValue(plusVal);

    theColumn = 2;//Column B

    theRng = sh.getRange(theRow,theColumn);

    currVal = theRng.getValue();
    minusVal = currVal - 1;
    theRng.setValue(minusVal);

    if (!currVal) {//If there is a blank cell then
      break;//quit the loop
    }

    theRow = theRow + 1;//Increment to the next row
  }

}catch(e) {
  Logger.log('message: ' + e.message);
  Logger.log('stack: ' + e.stack);
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that has actually makes sense now!

Comment: Thanks for letting me  know, and marking my answer as correct.