# I would like to have a script button which deducts values from column A to the the values of Column B

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to have a script button which deducts values from column A to the the values of Column B and the answer will be in Column C. I dont have any expertise in google script. Kindda beginner here

Comment: You could use a formula to do that instead of a script.   Is there a reason you feel you need a script to do it?

Comment: Do you mean B-A=C? As in "=B1-A1".